Most efficient way to sum-up subset of list
a = [-1, 17, 3, 101, -46, 51]

I want the sum of elements from an arbitrary start index to an arbitrary end index.
I can do this :
partial = sum(a[start:end+1])

But Python slice creates another list which consumes memory and might be time-inefficient.
Does Python offer a built-in function to sum a subarray efficiently ?

sum(itertools.islice(...))?

[sum(list(itertools.islice(....)

Python has a memoryview type which gives you the kind of direct access to the underlying memory of a value that would allow a list slice to be a quick view into the list, rather than a shallow (partial) copy of the list. list, however, does not currently support the buffer protocol that memoryview objects use. I thought I remembered reading that list would implement it soon (3.13, 3.14?) but I can't find anything to support that memory.

sum can operate directly on any iterable, including an islice object, anyway. It's inefficient, however, if start is large, because islice has to explicitly iterate through everything before start; it cannot simply jump to start. list supports random access, but the list_iterator object that islice works with does not.

Depends on the length of the list, what values start/end are, how much memory you have. We don't know any of that.

Define efficient for you. You can either optimize for speed or for memory. Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth

You can write your own sum_array in jit:
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

@jit("float64(List(float64, True), int64, int64)")
def sum_arr(data, st_index, end_index):
    sum = 0
    for i in prange(st_index, end_index):
        sum += data[i]
    return sum

x = list(np.random.randn(100))
res = sum_arr(x, 10,20)
print(res)

